# Python heapq : How do I sort the heap using nth element of the list of lists?

Tags: python

So I have lists of lists getting added to the heap; eg:

```
 n = [[1, 5, 93],
     [2, 6, 44],
     [4, 7, 45],
     [6, 3, 12]]

 heapq.heapify(n)
 print(n)
```

This compares and sorts according to the list's first element.

My question is, how do I sort the heapq so it compares the third element of each list? For example, the above list would be accessed from the heapq in this order:

```
[[6, 3, 12],
 [2, 6, 44],
 [4, 7, 45],
 [1, 5, 93]]
```

Comment: `sorted(your_list_of_lists,key=lambda x:x[2])`

Comment: Are you looking to just `sort` or do you have a number of inserts and removes?

Comment: I can't use anything else. I'm really tight on time complexity with the algorithm so I need to save me some big O's. Is there any way to get heapq itself to store the lists in the different order? (PS: I also edited the post to clarify some things)

Comment: `sorted()` is a fast as you will get if you are doing this only once, if you are trying to maintain a sorted structure over a number `push`s and `pop`s then a `heapq` makes sense.

Comment: AChampion - I need a sorted queue with log(n) push and pop.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`heapq` doesn't support a `key` function for it's ordering so you will need to manipulate your data structure. Mapping your list to a `tuple(sort_value, list)` will allow you to do `log(n)` push and pop:

```
 In []:
 q = [(x[2], x) for x in n]
 heapq.heapify(q)
 heapq.heappop(q)

 Out[]:
 (12, [6, 3, 12])

 In []:
 l = [2, 5, 1]
 heapq.heappush(q, (l[2], l))
 heapq.heappop(q)

 Out[]:
 (1, [2, 5, 1])
```

Alternatively, define your own `list` and implement the comparison function for that list:

```
class MyList(list):
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self[2] < other[2]

q = [MyList(x) for x in n]
```

Note: you should implement the other comparison functions (see `functools.total_ordering` on how to do that easily).